# How can I switch a background image in separate div using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty making one background-image transition to another using only CSS. What I'm trying to accomplish --> click on the .carrier1 or .carrier2 divs in the left column, the larger background-image of .map-block in the right column will change to another background-image corresponding to that carrier div.

Below is the code I've come up with so far. Not sure if it's written correctly as far as functionality goes. For the sake of not dealing with background images, I've substituted the images with colors.

HTML -

```
<div id="logistics">

    <div id="carriers">
        <div class="carrier1" tabindex="1">
            <img src="#" title="logo1" />
        </div>
        <div class="carrier2" tabindex="2">
            <img src="#" title="logo2" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map">
        <div class="map-block"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS -

```
.carrier1:focus,
.carrier2:focus {
    outline:none;
}

.carrier1:hover,
.carrier2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#map > .map-block {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#carriers > .carrier1:focus ~ #map > .map-block {
    background-color:red;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}

#carriers > .carrier2:focus ~ #map > .map-block {
    background-color:yellow;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;  
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you drop the `<div id="carriers">` wrapper you will be able to target the map-block

Comment: thanks @LGSon. I'm trying to keep #carriers and #map in 2 separate columns for structural reasons in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for can't be done... without modifying your HTML. Unfortunately, there is [no **parent** selector in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/). Thus, there is no way to target your `#map` from within `#carriers`. You are correctly making use of the tilde (`~`) selector to target the next relevant element, but this can **only** target **siblings**, and thus will only work from the same parent.

Essentially, this can only be solved with pure CSS by shifting `#map` inside `#carriers`:

```css
#carriers > .carrier1:focus ~ #map > .map-block {
  background-color: red;
  transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}

#carriers > .carrier2:focus ~ #map > .map-block {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="logistics">
  <div id="carriers">
    <div class="carrier1" tabindex="1">
      <img src="#" title="logo1" />
    </div>
    <div class="carrier2" tabindex="2">
      <img src="#" title="logo2" />
    </div>
    <div id="map">
      <div class="map-block">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Obsidian. This is what I was afraid of and needed to confirm.

What if I were to remove the #map div altogether, expand the #carriers div width with a padding-right to contain the background image of the map, and then float the .carrier1 & .carrier2 divs to the left, would I be able to switch the background-image then?

So, could I switch the background-image of the parent #carriers div when clicking on either child div .carrier1? or .carrier2?

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work either, as the same problem arises; you're trying to target the parent element. You can target the siblings, but you can never target the parent in CSS. Annoyingly, it's ridiculously easy with something like jQuery `($('.carrier1').parent())`, though with pure CSS, a sibling relationship is the best you can do. You'll have to find a way to work your display around that :)

Comment: Understood. It looks like I will have to go the jQuery route although I was trying to avoid it in order to keep load times to a minimum. :-/ Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped you :) If this answered your question, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Comment: You can always use vanilla JavaScript if you want to keep load times to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHain. I've tried the following JavaScript with the same HTML and CSS I used in my original question but, I'm getting the following error: "$ is not defined"
<script>
$('.carrier1').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).getElementsByClassName('.map-block').css('background-image', 'url("../assets/images/logistics-map1.jpg")');
     }).blur(
     function(){
         $(this).getElementsByClassName('.map-block').css('background-image', 'url("../assets/images/logistics-map2.jpg")')
     });
</script>
See anything I am missing or did wrong?

Comment: @apexturtle - That means that you have not included jQuery. It's possible to use raw JavaScript, but you can't use any `$` (jQuery) methods. A full list of methods you would need can be found [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). I personally really wouldn't worry about the overheads from jQuery though, as they're incredibly low, and jQuery really does make everything so much simpler :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge - I realized my mistake after posting my previous comment. I had placed that script code before calling the jQuery library. >.< Thanks for the jQuery methods reference. That is something I've been looking for for a while. I was able to accomplish what I needed by using the hover function in jQuery.